# multiple images in CardMedia ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i have multiple images within one CardMedia ? or is it possible to do that ?

Maybe one as a cover and other asa set of small images at the bottom of the cover.

[image: ScreenShot]

```
         <CardMedia
          component="img"
          className={classes.media}
          height="140"
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with the same issue.
In my case needed to show a list of images aligned horizontally.
Here is the code that worked for me perfectly:

```js
    <Card>
      <CardMedia height="100">
        <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: '100%', overflow: 'auto' }} spacing={5} justifyContent="center">
          {product.images.map((image) => (
            <img src={image.url} key={image.url} />
          ))}
        </Stack>
      </CardMedia>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
          {product.fullName}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button>Add image</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
```

Here is what I've got:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not possible, according to their official API documentation.

What you could do is as a component prop, instead of passing img as a prop you can pass a function (API says that you can do that) that can call this component: https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/#mobile-stepper-text-with-carousel-effect

It will not do exactly what you want, but it could be really really similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a carousel by yourself and feed that into CardMedia children Props.

like:

```
<CartMedia children={<YourCarousal />} />
```

Answer (score -1):

this Work nice for me

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   media: {
    paddingTop: "100%",
    backgroundImage: "url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0436/7482/8957/products/p1_large.jpg?v=1597924393)",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    transition: "0.5s ease",
    "&:hover": {
        backgroundImage: "url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0436/7482/8957/products/p3_1415dff1-c937-4300-9eaf-38d1e12a0581_large.jpg?v=1597924399)",
    },
},
```

Dont forget `const classes = useStyles()`
then add media classe in  `CardMedia`

```
<CardMedia
    className={classes.media}
/>
```